# "self.to_a" works but "self.to_a.join('').gsub(/\W/,"")" not

Tags: ruby

my code has passed all the test conditions( for example, arrays, strings, hash..) except this one:

```
ValidPalindromeTest.new(81,96).palindrome?
```

it should return true but doesn't. The code is:

```
class String
  def palindrome?     
    self.gsub(/\W/,"").downcase == self.gsub(/\W/,"").downcase.reverse
  end
end

module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    if self.is_a?(Hash)
      false
    else
      self.to_a.join('').gsub(/\W/,"").downcase == self.to_a.join('').gsub(/\W/,"").downcase.reverse
    end
  end
end
```

But when I change to

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    if self.is_a?(Hash)
      false
    else
      self.to_a == self.to_a.reverse
    end
end
```

It works.

The question is what is the type of `ValidPalindromeTest.new(81,96)`? It should be an instance of `ValidPalindromeTest` type, right? How can the second method passed the `auto_grader` while first one can't? Because in my mind as long as `self.to_a` works, the rest (`.join('').gsub(/\W/,"").downcase`) should work too.

Comment: maybe you could show what `self.to_a` gives you

Comment: 1) How is 81 a palindrome of 96? 2) What is the `auto_grader` you reference? 3) Can you post your unit tests? 4) Not really related to your question, but...I don't know how efficient your `palindrome` method has to be, but you're at an O(n^2) solution (from the `#==`). There's a simple, though less Ruby-like, algorithm available (just loop over the chars and compare the ends, e.g,. `chars[head_index] == chars[tail_index]`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what are you trying to do, but if your goal is set a method that knows whether an array is a 'palindrome' or not, I think the first method will evaluate true is you pass an array like `%w( ani ta la va la ti na )` and the second will evaluate true with an array like `[0,2,3,2,0]`, wich means those methods evaluate different things, and wont return both true if you test them with the same object. The first method evaluation is more complex an does something different. However, if you are triying to mix that method in Enumerable, why the `self.to_a`?